# What are the recommended failure strategies when manually allocating memory in C?

Tags: c, out-of-memory, heap-memory

What are the different and more importantly the recommended failure strategies when manually allocating memory in C? I am assuming that the code doesn't run in a  resource constrained environment but on a typical PC. Therefore there should usually be plenty of memory available and different parallel processes will likely allocate and free memory all the time.

Consider the following example:

```c
char* buf = (char*) malloc (0xFFFF * sizeof(char));
if (buf == NULL) {
    // What now?
}
```

Is the following code a reasonable solution if we assume that the amount of memory available changes all the time?

```c
char* buf = (char*) malloc (0xFFFF * sizeof(char));
while (buf == NULL) {
    sleep(1000);  // Random delay
    buf = (char*) malloc (0xFFFF * sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: The amount of *contiguous* free memory might not change as much as you think. If the OS reports out of memory, you should consider it to be actually and properly out of memory, and treat it as a fatal error. Either that or attempt to free up memory in your *own* process and retry once. If the second attempt (after cleaning up) also fails, then it's really fatal.

Comment: It cannot be answered without knowing a broader context, but oftentimes out-of-memory failures are considered catstrophic and  crashing the application is a reasonable solution. But again "context is king" and without it all can be stated are the usual rules of thumb.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how should I handle  it then? Simply emit an error and give up (i.e. exit) if the allocation fails?

Comment: Or abort, which is a less graceful exit but usually leaves a crash dump for post-mortem debugging.

Comment: @alagner This  question occurred to me while I was writing a parser and allocating memory for arrays which are meant to hold a linear stream of parse tokens. There isn't really any memory which can could free. Also in a parser/compiler I guess exiting with an error isn't too  bad.

Comment: Given how modern operating systems work (virtual memory, swap space, ...), you are more likely to get your application terminated by signal than receiving a failure from malloc anyway. And since there are many apps running concurrently, your chances to reliably recover are next to nil. Sometimes giving up is acceptable. ;-)

Comment: Well, GCC does just it ;)

Comment: Out of memory situation on some systems may happen just because OS is set to memory quota for single process. Depending on purpose and context, the actions may be different.

Comment: But is your parser *that* important? Unless you hold *vital* information in *this* instance of your program, why bother? Let the user recover some memory and run your app again.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't know any modern OS where user's actions would help. Unless process just had hit the memory quote set on system. On modern OS processes summarily can use far more memory than physically available. It's likely either fragmentation problem or you had reached OS's or ISA limit. E.g. in x86-32 bit mode on Windows you'e limited to 2.3 or 2 Gb, regardless what, on x86-32 linux to 4 Gb and that includes fragmentation. Even if your app is running on x64bit OS with 0.5Tb of RAM. But on 32 linux process in theory could use 2Gb of memory while cimputer had 2Gb tital. Ust agressive paging

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The user could close the raytracer he's running concurrently. Shut down the minecraft server. Reboot the system to remove the memory fragmentation. Get more RAM or assign a larger swap space. All things far out of scope for what your app can do, or should attempt.

Comment: @DevSolar that increase performance. Not "free" virtual memory for different process. You have try really hard to overcome memory manager which would push other processes out of physical memory. There are narrow set of situations where process have to stay "physical", mainly kernel and varous system infrastructure

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yet obviously the malloc failed, so your system is in deep trouble anyhow. What is the point you are arguing?

Comment: @DevSolar Not system. My process. Without knowing platform it's hard to theorise. Let assume desktop, linux 64 bit, 16 Gb. Currently my Chrome browser takes up... 23Gb total, being actually 19 different processes. It jungles data between them. The html parser is actally separate proccess, so called "headless rider" spawned. They can individually run out of memory, there is cintingencies to solve the issue. Another would be created, the "dying" one would leave its legacy as a cache. All process on system "use" far more memory than it presents. But each is limited to 6Gb total by system setting.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie It seems to me you're talking to someone else, as you seem to have *completely* missed my whole point. Either you need to *desperately* save whatever data you're handling, or you don't. Either way, it's not up to your application to find a solution for a system running out of memory. Malloc fails, you exit. Either immediately or after saving your data. Exceptions notwithstanding, which should be rare.

Comment: Would it be better to pre-empt the situation and somehow check what percentage of virtual memory, if available, is being used and try to abort in an orderly way if its say over 50%? Does anyone know how to check this in program?

Comment: @SimonGoater If your application uses up *virtual* memory to the point where it might run out, it becomes an *architectural* issue. As virtual memory usage is all up to your application anyway, you should be aware of where you are allocating the majority of that memory, and be logging those allocations yourself.

Comment: It could be any application that uses the virtual memory up, maybe a memory leak. I thought it would be prudent to monitor its usage and perform an orderly abort if it gets too large. Once it gets to the point where malloc fails, its too late to reliably do anything useful to save the situation.

Comment: @SimonGoater If your memory is virtual, yours is the only appliction living in that memory space...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a counter and a conditional exit after N tries, inside the while, to avoid infinite loop. Additionally, you'll need to decide what to do if memory allocation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since even printf allocates an output buffer there is little that you can do to either recover or to notify the user. Anything other than abort is likely a waste of time and adds untestable code. You could do what UNIX did which is never check but use the NULL pointer as soon as possible to help debug where the crash occurs. I'm too lazy to find the Ken Thompson quote.

Comment: *Since even printf allocates an output buffer*  `write()` doesn't...